# How can I parse nested source files with ANTLR4?

Tags: antlr4

I've asked this question before (slightly differently) but didn't understand the answers enough at the time to give intelligent feedback (sigh).

I need to be able to include files inside other files at arbitrary points so I need to be able to have a stack of files with a single parse tree.

If I was writing this myself (and I have done this in the past), my parser would recognize the "Include xyz" or "Import abc", and would cause the lexer to suspend reading from the current file, push that file on a stack, and continue reading characters from the new file until exhausted.

However, when using **ANTLR4** (where so far I've avoided inserting any code into the grammar file itself) and using the visitor pattern, all I see is the created tree which of course is too late.

I've found references to PUSHSTREAM as something that can be done in the lexer but I cannot find an actual example and would really appreciate some help (either a pointer to an actual example that I perhaps missed when searching or a short code sample if someone has one).

Note that I'm writing code in C++, not Java.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Years ago I developed a solution for ANTLR 2.7, to [parse Windows resource files](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php/java/windows-resource-file-parser-and-converter) (*.rc). Such files are structured very much like C/C++ header files and support preprocessor directives like #if/#end/#pragma/#include.

For that I created a special character input stream (with a nested char input stream) which implements a stack based approach for include files. Whenever a new include directive is found in the char input a new stack entry is created with the current actual input stream, its position and line/column information (to provide local source locations, in case a parsing problem was found). That entry is pushed onto a stack and a new input stream is created. Once this is exhausted the TOS is popped off the stack and serving chars continued from the last position (after the #include statement). The lexer only sees a continuous stream of characters.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that in an earlier search and looked at your RCConverter.java but

a) I'm working in C++
b) I'm using ANTLR 4
c) There is supposed to be a built-in way to do this already using PUSHSTREAM

I just can't find that info anywhere.

Comment: I just see you asked this question in February already (without getting a useful answer). Can you point me to that "PUSHSTREAM" you mentioned? I'm not able to find anything like that in the ANTLR4 source code. And regarding Java: it shouldn't be a big problem for you to convert examples from Java to C++. Don't reject solutions just because they are not written in the language you prefer.

Comment: Yeah, story of my life - ask a question, get no answer --- ask again in a year and I just find my original question!   I'm fluent in Java --- just wanted to mention that I was using C++.   The example that I found was [here](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/ANTLR3/pages/2686987/How+do+I+implement+include+files) but it's for ANTRL3 and assumes that one will be embedding code directly in the grammar. ANTLR4 lets you avoid putting code in the grammar, which of course makes everything much cleaner and so I was struggling to see how to get the ANTLR3 example working in ANTLR4