# How can I parse nested source files with ANTLR4 - Trying one more time

Tags: antlr4

I found the code (reproduced below) in an article from Terrence Parr showing how INCLUDE files could be handled in ANTLR3 for Java. I tried to add this to a grammar I use with ANTLR4 (with a C++ target) but when I tried to generate a parser, I got the errors

```
error(50): : syntax error: '^' came as a complete surprise to me 
error(50): : syntax error: mismatched input '->' expecting SEMI while matching a rule 
error(50): : syntax error: '^' came as a complete surprise to me 
error(50): : syntax error: '(' came as a complete surprise to me while matching rule preamble
```

and I have no idea what these error means. Can anyone explain and perhaps show me the way forward?

(NB: I'm not wild about polluting the grammar file with code, I'm using the visitor pattern but I'll take it if I can!)

Thanks

```
include_filename :
  ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '.' | '_')+
;

include_statement
@init { CommonTree includetree = null; }
 :
  'include' include_filename ';' {
    try {
      CharStream inputstream = null;
      inputstream = new ANTLRFileStream($include_filename.text);
      gramLexer innerlexer = new gramLexer(inputstream);
      gramParser innerparser = new gramParser(new CommonTokenStream(innerlexer));
      includetree = (CommonTree)(innerparser.program().getTree());
    } catch (Exception fnf) {
      ;
    }
  }
  -> ^('include' include_filename ^({includetree}))
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with ANTLR4 it is no longer possible to manipulate the generated parse tree with grammar rules. In fact ANTLR3 generated an AST (abstract syntax tree), which is a subset of a parse tree (as generated by ANTLR4). That in turn means you cannot keep the tree rewrite syntax (the part starting with `->`). Hence you should change the code to:

```
include_statement
@init { CommonTree includetree = null; }
 :
  'include' Include_filename ';' {
    try {
      CharStream inputstream = null;
      inputstream = new ANTLRFileStream($include_filename.text);
      gramLexer innerlexer = new gramLexer(inputstream);
      gramParser innerparser = new gramParser(new CommonTokenStream(innerlexer));
      includetree = (CommonTree)(innerparser.program().getTree());
    } catch (Exception fnf) {
      ;
    }
  }
;
```

Comment: Thank you - having never used ANTLR3, I didn't know what that syntax represented. I will try it.

Comment: Hmm, this needs some changes to be used in a C++ platform. I'm not familiar with how to include C++ headers in an ANTLR grammar file and (after "C++'fying that Java code) when I generate the parser and try to compile it, CommonTree, gramLexer and gramParser are unknown.

Comment: That's a different problem and you should ask a separate question for that (and mention that this is about the C++ target). Here I answered you the question what the errors are you see and how to fix them.

Comment: Yeah - been there, done that --- I've asked this several times in the past (hence the title of this question including the tag "Trying one more time". Nobody seems to know how to support INCLUDE for C++ parsers created with ANTLR4

Comment: Can you point me to one of the other questions? I can give some input there. And you should change the question title, as this is mostly about the errors you got when you converted ANTLR3 to 4 grammar code.

Comment: Sure --- see for example this link.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56414394/how-can-i-parse-nested-source-files-with-antlr4

Comment: Well, what I meant was that you should ask a dedicated question about properly making this work with C++. This requires to post the relevant parts of your generated files and the exact error message etc.

Comment: My original question (on that other link) asked explicitly how to handle include files and in the content of the message I said explicitly that I was using C++, not Java. The question HERE was asked after I found what I THOUGHT might be a solution but it turns out not to work. As I mentioned in an earlier comment in this thread, the error was that "CommonTree, gramLexer and gramParser are unknown