# I need a mechanism to allow include files to be handled in ANTLR4 with a C++ runtime

Tags: c++, antlr4

I am looking for a way to allow a language developed using ANTLR4 to support the concept of an include file. I need it to work with the C++ runtime version of ANTLR4.

I tried using code I found from ANTLR3 but got errors due to changes between ANTRL3 and ANTRL4.  That example was corrected by Mike Lischke  (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59101124/57246) which the parser generator could handle but the generated C++ code does not compile. I get the following kinds of errors:

1) The statement **CommonTree* includetree = nullptr;** and  **gramLexer* innerlexer = new gramLexer(inputstream);** produce errors

```
  Unknown type name 'CommonTree'
  Unknown type name 'gramLexer
```

2) The **catch (Exception fnf)** clause results in

```
  Unknown type name 'Exception'
```

I don't know if there's a fundamental issue here or whether some extra C++ header files are required but I'm stuck and would really appreciate some help.

Thanks

Comment: The title of this question is confusing. Your problem is about normal C++ compilation, not include handling in an ANTLTR4 generated parser/lexer. The type errors seem to indicate that you are missing a header file or two.

Comment: I have realized that part of the issue (as far as compiling is concerned at least) is that those class names "gramLexer", "gramParser", etc are actually supposed to based on the name of my grammar.  The use of the prefix "gram" was totally misleading (since I'm not an ANTLR expert)

Comment: I'm making progress now but I'm stuck with a new ANTLR issue. I'm now able to get the subtree using a corrected version of the code I originally posted at (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59097205/how-can-i-parse-nested-source-files-with-antlr4-trying-one-more-time/59101124#59101124) but how do I attach that included tree into the parent tree so that after parsing is complete, the code generation section gets a complete tree that has the included parts in it?

Comment: By the way, once I've put all the pieces together, I'm going to write up a blog on how to do this since there doesn't seem to be a single place that shows how to do this for C++, and there are many requests from people to do it

Comment: SO is not the right place for discussions about follow up errors and the course of actions to implement such a task. For that better use the ANTLR mailing list.

Comment: People still use mailing lists? Sigh!